# How do I change the color of git plugin in oh my zsh

Tags: git, zsh, prompt, oh-my-zsh

I'm on a M1 Macbook Air. I have installed `Oh My Zsh` and `zsh-autosuggestions`. When I `cd` into a directory that has `git` initialized, the `git` plugin comes on and it looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlmhA.png. How do I change the color of this to light blue?

Comment: Please refer to zsh themes https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes. You can [customise a theme](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Customization#overriding-and-adding-themes).